# RecyclerView scrolling laggy on newer android versions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, lag

My `RecyclerView` is pretty laggy whenever I start to scroll over the first items in a cold app start. This behavior happens for the latest android versions (tested on API level 27 and 28) but not older ones (tested on API level 22).

I tried both versions, the normal `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` and androidx `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03`.

The test project is pretty simple:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<String> mData;
Context context;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.mData = data;
    this.context = context;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public String getItem(int id) {
    return mData.get(id);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_tv);
    }
}
}
```

recycler_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any ideas for solving the problem or is it a library issue which can't be solved by myself (waiting for new official release)?

Comment: Have you tried removing setItemViewCacheSize and noticed a difference?

Comment: Yes, I did (also setHasFixedSize(true)) but no difference. In the GPU Profiler the bars are reaching the top of the screen (almost green), later, when it's "loaded" it keeps in 16ms area.

Comment: any changes when _not_ using ConstraintLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the build variant to release after finding this comment: [Performance of ConstraintLayout inside RecyclerView ViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604562/performance-of-constraintlayout-inside-recyclerview-viewholder#comment90175027_51604562).

The example shared here is smoothly then and my application with Glide performs more smoothly, too, even without setting layout_width to ConstraintLayout.

But it's unclear to me why this lag appears in the debug mode and only on the latest android versions.

Answer (score 4):

In you item layout the wrapper class is `ConstraintLayout` with `wrap_content_height` - it could cause problems while measuring.

- Since you have a single itme inside you could just get rid of wrapper and keep just single TextView as a root element
- If you still wants to get wrapper for the view - try to avoid wrap_content for `RelativeLayout` and/or `ConstrainLayout`, use fix size or simple layouts such as Frame/Linear.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, can anyone explain why wrap_content causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same problem and solved by using recyclerview within nested scroll view. like below code:

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@id/ListBannerAds">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:id="@+id/ZaboorListRecyclerview"/>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Man, Thank you so much! I've been rewriting adapters since 3 days and nothing worked until I saw this solution. Thank you from all my heart and hate android development from all my heart too.

Comment: nice working on android 12

Answer (score 2):

get `layoutInflater`from parent context so instead of

```
mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, viewGroup, false);
```

use this

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, viewGroup,
                    false);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Nothing changed, still lags